# Not able to install selenium IDE on any of the browser 38,47,54 & 55

Tags: selenium-ide

request you all please help,i m not able to Not able to install selenium IDE on any of the browser 38,47,54 & 55.

please help.

Answer (score 5):

Selenium IDE has [stopped working since Firefox 55](https://medium.com/@briananderson2209/in-search-of-the-selenium-ides-successor-33bc7eaefe7f). There are some [workarounds](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/08/08/firefox-your-options-to-run-legacy-add-ons/), the quickest and safest way is to install [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/) (until June 26, 2018).

Anyway, Selenium IDE is a legacy project dating back to the days of Selenium RC. The last time it got updated was in 2015. It will not work in other browsers, and new web technology is reducing its helpfulness. You should consider learning another Selenium-based tool e.g. [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/), [Katalon Studio](https://www.katalon.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=stackoverflow), [Protractor](http://protractortest.org/), [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/), [Watir](http://watir.com/) etc. I think for now feature-wise the only free alternative to Selenium IDE is Katalon Studio.

Comment: Cerys thanks,but my concern specifically with IDE ,i have idea what u talking about.so please suggest which for version of FF ,does IDE works,thanx

Comment: Firefox 54, or Firefox ESR as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using firefox browser.Go to http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ 
scroll down and download the ide. Another window for plug in  will be opened and add that to your firefox .it may require a restart and after that go to developer toolbal and open selenuim ide. This is the usual step and if this is not working,you can manually download selenium_ide-2.9.1-fx.xpi file.since it extension is xpi,try opening  with firefox by clicking on properties.This will work even on version 55.